# XSD attribute. Make use="required" by default

Tags: xml, xsd

The title says it all. How can I change the default value of use, of any attribute from optional to required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid this won't be possible, in http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cAttribute_Declarations is written: *{required} true if the use [attribute] is present with ·actual value· required, otherwise false.*